# Gradient & Newton method for optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

I have the following function to minimize using both gradient and Newton's method

> $\mathcal f(x_1,x_2)= 36x_1+36x_2+5x_1^2+5x_2^2+8x_1x_2$

Using an initial points $x^0=0$ for the gradient method, I found out that the next point $x^1$ for the first iteration is $(-4,-4)$ and also the point after, in general I get the same result from the beginning and it doesn't change.
My question is , is this the optimum?? and if there is anymore explanation for this result can you explain it to me ?

the second second question is about the Newton's method, I found some problems applying this one can any one help me, figure out how to use the Newton's method to minimize this function ? (I don't want the result, just how to apply the method)

Comment: There is no constraint, I have another starting point $x_1=x_2=3$ but I did'nt try to solve it yet with this starting point, I want to know if the result for  $x_1=x_2=0$ is normal or not? or maybe I did something wrong because I've  done it several times and the result is the same. and also the exercice is telling me to use just these two starting points $0$ and $3$

Comment: Do you know the Newton's method iteration?  What goes wrong when you try to apply it?

Comment: @littleO Actually I'm not familiar with the method and I didn't start solving the problem with it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

$x_1 = u+v\\
x_2 = u-v$

$f(u,v) = $$5u^2 + 10uv + 5v^2 + 5u^2 - 10uv + 10v^2 + 8u^2 - 8v^2 + 36u + 36v + 36u - 36v\\
18u^2 + 2v^2 + 72u\\
18(u+4)^2 + 2v^2 - 72$

The minimum is at $(-4,0)$ in $u,v$ space and $(-2,-2)$ in $x,y$ space.

Alternatively you could find $x_1,x_2$ such that:

$\nabla f(x_1,x_2) = \mathbf 0$

Provided that $\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_2} -  (\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2})^2>0$

$\nabla f(x_1,x_2)$ always points in the direction to most quickly increase the value of $f(x_1,x_2)$, and $-\nabla f(x_1,x_2)$ points in the direction to reduce it.  If $f(x_1,x_2)$ is at a minimum, there is no way to go that will reduce it, therefore $\nabla f(x_1,x_2) = \mathbf 0$

This is a necessary but not sufficient condition.  If $\nabla f(x_1,x_2) = \mathbf 0$ you could be at a maximum, a minimum or a saddle.   Enter the second derivative tests.

$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_2} -  (\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2})^2<0$
means you have a saddle.

$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_2} -  (\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2})^2>0$

Indicates either a maximum or a minimum.

$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}, \frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_2} < 0$  implies a maximum.

$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}, \frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_2} > 0$ 
implies a minimum.

I am not sure how I would apply Newton's method.  Newton's method is great for finding 0's, but not necessarily minima.

Comment: so the minimum is at $(-2,-2)$ I must have done some mistake but I did'nt get your alternative solution can you please explain it a little more. and btw $\nabla f(x_1,x_2)=(10x_1+8x_2+36,8x_1+10x_2+36)$

Comment: Newton's method is often used for finding minima (or extrema).  The key idea is that you can use Newton's method (for root-finding) to find solutions to $\nabla f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Doug Thanks you made things clearer

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I just made a mistake calculating a derivative @DougM you were right the minimum is (-2,-2) and had it after one Iteration for both initial points and for the Newton's method as well